# Handlebars does not appear to allow me to access an array inside my object passed to the template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

This problem only just appeared when I migrated my code to production, it does not happen in my development environment.

I have a handlebars template which receives an object, something like:

```
{node: {sections: [{name: 'abc'},{name: 'xyz'}]}}
```

The template looks like this:

```
{{#each node.sections}}
  {{#ifCond type '==' "image-left-text-right"}}
    {{> admin/section/image-left-text-right}} 
  {{/ifCond}}
  {{#ifCond type '==' "two-columns-image-and-text"}}
    {{> admin/section/two-columns-image-and-text}} 
  {{/ifCond}}
  {{#ifCond type '==' "four-columns"}}
  {{> admin/section/four-columns}} 
  {{/ifCond}}     
{{/each}}
```

Now this all looks great in my development environment and the template renders correctly, in production nothing shows.

After console logging my entire object I can confirm it's there, wrote a little helper to help me console log it:

```
<script>
  console.log('----1---')
  console.log({{{json node}}})
  console.log('----2---')
  console.log({{{json node.sections}}})
  console.log('----3---')
</script>
```

What is super weird, is that console.log on the node returns:
[image]

However the second console log outputs nothing.

It is like it doesn't have access to that attribute on the object?

I'm running version handlebars@4.7.6 in both dev and prod. Is there some weird private/public flag I'm not aware off in Handlebars I need to set, to allow it to access the array directly?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently I was wrong, I'm running 4.0.12 in dev and 4.7.6 in production. the ^4.0.12 in the package.json file caused it to install the newer version. Apparently the issue is related to 4.7.6, for now I've changed it to 4.0.12 and will eventually investigate what changes in 4.7.6 have caused this problem.